# Solve the functional equation $f(4x(1-x))=\sin(\pi f(x))$ for find an invariant measure of a dynamical system $x_{n+1}=\sin(\pi x_{n})$

Tags: functional-equations, ergodic-theory

I need solve the funcional equation 
$$f(4x(1-x))=\sin(\pi f(x))\tag{1}$$

**Remark:** I have tried to solve this equation but I have only reached a reformulation:
$$
\frac{4(1-2y)f'(4y(1-y))}{\sqrt{1-f^{2}(4y(y-1))}}=\pi f'(y)
.$$

**Edit:**
 This question is motivated by a problem of Ergodic Theory, the problem is find  invarian measure of dynamical system
$$x_{n+1}=\sin(\pi x_{n}).\tag{2}$$
For this purpose it is sufficient to find its invariant density. In this sense, the idea is find a  function $f$ inyective such thar satisfies (1) with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. If that function existed then we have a change of coordinates given by
$$x=f(y).$$
Therefore, sustituting in (2) we have $f(y_{n+1})=\sin(\pi f(y_{n}))$, but by (1) we have
$$ f(y_{n+1})=f(4 y_{n}(1-y_{n})) .$$
Since we assume that $f$ injective then
$$y_{n+1}=4y_{n}(1-y_{n}) \tag{3}.$$
But we know the invariant probability density function of dynamical system (3) is the function 
$$\rho(x)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{x(1-x)}}.$$
Therefore, the invariant probability density function g of dynamical system (1) is the function
$$g(x)=\left|\frac{df(x)}{dx}\right|\rho(x).$$
Therefore, the whole problem is reduced to finding $f$.

Comment: One solution is $f(t) = 0$ for all $t$.

Comment: 1) Why do you look at it as a differential equation problem? 2) Where does the problem come from? (this could help us very much to solve it in general) 3) From the user name of @md2perpe I conclude we studied at the same university. Cheers from md9per.

Comment: Det stämmer. Jag är också mdstud:are.